# cargo execution - permission denied [PREVIOUSLY]rust installation - permission denied

Tags: permissions, fstab, home

I have installed rust by `curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh` and followed instructions thereof. Installation was successful and the **PATH** was added to the `.bash_profile` as follows:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH
```

echo ing `$PATH` shows variable has been set properly, as follows:

```
rust@rusty:~$ echo $PATH
/home/rust/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
```

I am mounting `/home` as a separate partition and mounting through `/etc/fstab` as follows

```
# Mounting home partition
/dev/sda4                 /home                 ext4      rw,async,users      0 0
```

I initially had `noexec` as one of the options. But, removing that did not bring any change in the outcome.

I doubting that my default `/home` partition permissions but don't have any other linux running box to verify.

```
total 20
drwx------  2 root     root     16384 Jan 18 08:38 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 22 rust     rust     4096  Jan 19 19:45 rust
```

Is this permissions correct?

If someone could shed some light on what I am missing to notice/doing wrong and how to troubleshoot and fix the issue would be much appreciated.

Realized after the comment from @kusalananda

**EDIT-1**

```
rust@rusty:~$ cargo
bash: /home/rust/.cargo/bin/cargo: Permission denied
```

It supposed to prompt me with the help documentation of `cargo` but fails saying the above.

**EDIT-2**
Added the permissions of `.cargo` and `.cargo/bin`

```
rust@rusty:~$ ls -l .cargo/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 rust rust 4096 Jan 19 18:45 bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 rust rust   37 Jan 19 18:58 env
rust@rusty:~$ ls -l .cargo/bin/
total 108560
-rwxr-xr-x 10 rust rust 11116056 Jan 19 18:45 cargo
-rwxr-xr-x 10 rust rust 11116056 Jan 19 18:45 cargo-clippy
-rwxr-xr-x 10 rust rust 11116056 Jan 19 18:45 cargo-fmt
-rwxr-xr-x 10 rust rust 11116056 Jan 19 18:45 rls
-rwxr-xr-x 10 rust rust 11116056 Jan 19 18:45 rustc
-rwxr-xr-x 10 rust rust 11116056 Jan 19 18:45 rustdoc
-rwxr-xr-x 10 rust rust 11116056 Jan 19 18:45 rustfmt
-rwxr-xr-x 10 rust rust 11116056 Jan 19 18:45 rust-gdb
-rwxr-xr-x 10 rust rust 11116056 Jan 19 18:45 rust-lldb
-rwxr-xr-x 10 rust rust 11116056 Jan 19 18:45 rustup
```

**EDIT-3**:

```
>> curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
info: downloading installer

Welcome to Rust!

This will download and install the official compiler for the Rust programming 
language, and its package manager, Cargo.

It will add the cargo, rustc, rustup and other commands to Cargo's bin 
directory, located at:

  /home/rusty/.cargo/bin

This path will then be added to your PATH environment variable by modifying the
profile files located at:

  /home/rusty/.profile
  /home/rusty/.bash_profile

You can uninstall at any time with rustup self uninstall and these changes will
be reverted.

Current installation options:

   default host triple: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
     default toolchain: stable
  modify PATH variable: yes

1) Proceed with installation (default)
2) Customize installation
3) Cancel installation
>1

info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: latest update on 2019-01-17, rust version 1.32.0 (9fda7c223 2019-01-16)
info: downloading component 'rustc'
 79.5 MiB /  79.5 MiB (100 %) 883.2 KiB/s ETA:   0 s                
info: downloading component 'rust-std'
 54.3 MiB /  54.3 MiB (100 %) 611.2 KiB/s ETA:   0 s                
info: downloading component 'cargo'
  4.4 MiB /   4.4 MiB (100 %) 761.4 KiB/s ETA:   0 s                
info: downloading component 'rust-docs'
  8.5 MiB /   8.5 MiB (100 %) 553.6 KiB/s ETA:   0 s                
info: installing component 'rustc'
info: installing component 'rust-std'
info: installing component 'cargo'
info: installing component 'rust-docs'
info: default toolchain set to 'stable'

  stable installed - (error reading rustc version)


Rust is installed now. Great!

To get started you need Cargo's bin directory ($HOME/.cargo/bin) in your PATH 
environment variable. Next time you log in this will be done automatically.

To configure your current shell run source $HOME/.cargo/env
```

Comment: You are not actually saying what prompts a "Permission denied" error.  Also, did you re-mount `/home` after changing `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: @Kusalananda. Yes. I did remount and even rebooted once to be sure.

Comment: The permissions on `/home/rust` looks ok. The allow for anyone to access the directory and read files therein.  What about `/home/rust/bin` and the `cargo` binary itself?

Comment: Thank you @Kusalananda. I have added the permissions of `.cargo` and `.cargo/bin`. My impression is that they're o.k. Please correct me, if otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the `/etc/fstab` entry that I had. It worked after I changed the way I was mounting. Here is my new `fstab` entry:

```
/dev/sda4            /home/rusty            ext4            defaults            0  2
```

I changed the owner & group of `/home/rusty` to be `rusty` and it worked.